# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings" about one line if condition

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm just starting new about knockout js because of a project so I tried to write one line condition in data-bind= text

so here is my code;

```
<div 
 data-bind="text: $data.status.value === '50' ? {{ _('Cancelled') }}
 : $data.status.value === '600' ? {{ _('Approved') }}
 : {{ _('Unknown') }},
 css: { hide: !$data.is_cancelled }"
>
</div>
```

and I got error like this;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
> Bindings value:
> data-bind="text: $data.status.value === '50' ? Anulat
> : $data.status.value === '600' ? Abrovat
> : Necunoscut,
> css: { hide: !$data.is_cancelled }"
> Message: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Although I'm not actually familiar with knockout.js, I guess you have two ternary operators nested which looks wrong. Try to surround the second ternary operator (the : and ? syntax) with brackets.

Comment: Shouldn't you enclose the `{{ ... }}` in single quotes, like you did "50" and "600"? In the error it looks like `{{ _('Cancelled') }}` expanded to "Anulat" directly.

Comment: @SparkFountain I tried this code block on console and it works so I don't think problem about brackets.    


let a = '100';
a === '50' ? console.log('Cancelled')
: a === '600' ? console.log('Approved')
: console.log('Unknown')

Comment: @rid I think you right some point. I notice that I forget ' before and after {{ _('Cancelled') }}.  I will try. Thanks mate

Comment: what is that `{{ _('Cancelled') }}` never seen this in knockout and this throws error of course

Answer (score 0):

those brackets {{ can not be at that point

you problably mistaking by being used to js-template-engine-libraries and want

```
$data.status.value === '50' ? _('Cancelled') : $data.status.value === '600' ? _('Approved')  :  _('Unknown')
```

where `function _(v){}` is probably some translation stuff

Comment: I am using {{ _('Cancelled') }} because of translations. I solved the problem 1 week ago. One ' is more on code :(